# Nested partials in mustache and loading partials from external file

Tags: jquery, partials, mustache

i have one burning question here

is it possible to nest a partial in another partial
this is what i am trying to do

```
-----------
index.html:
-----------
<html>
<head>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="mustache.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript.js"></script>
 <script src="json1.js"></script>
 <script src="json2.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div id="mustacheContainer"></div>
</body>
<html>

--------------
test.mustache: (this file contains main template and partials)
--------------
<script id="tpl-one" type="text/html"><!--main template -->
{{fname}}
{{> tplThree}}
</script>

<script id="tpl-two" type="text/html">
{{lname}}
</script>

<script id="tpl-three" type="text/html">
{{> tplTwo}}
</script>

---------
json1.js:
---------
var user={
 fname:'joe',
 lname:'blogs',
}

---------
json2.js:
---------
var translations={
 someword:'its translation'
}

-------------------
javascript.js file:
-------------------
;$(function () {
    $.get('test.mustache', function(templates) {
        var template = $(templates).filter('#tpl-one').html();
        $.extend(json1,json2);
        var three = $(templates).filter('#tpl-three').html();
        three = {"tplThree": one};
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, json1, three);
        $('#confirmationMustacheContainer').html(html);
    }, "html");

});
```

**Now the Question**
why is this not working? what am i doing wrong, is this context issue or nesting is not supported in mustache, is there any way to do this? using jquery, and how can i load partials from external files?

these are lot of question i hope someone can answer as it will help many users
i will give 5 ups for this one :)

thanks

Comment: stackoverflow, does not allow you to give 5 ups, unless you offer a bounty.:)

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is clean up your variables and properly form your partials object. `json1` and `json2` are not defined and should be `user` and `translations` respectively. You're overwriting the `three` template with what looks like your partial object that references an undefined `one`.

Your partial object needs to have the template names as keys (i.e. `tplTwo`) and the partial text as the value (i.e. `{{lname}}`).

Here's the cleaned up code:

```
// json1.js
var user = {
    fname: 'joe',
    lname: 'blogs',
}
// json2.js
var translations = {
    someword: 'its translation'
}

$.get('test.mustache', function(templates) {
    var json = $.extend(user, translations),
        one = $(templates).filter('#tpl-one').html(),
        three = $(templates).filter('#tpl-three').html(),
        two = $(templates).filter('#tpl-two').html(),
        partials = {
            "tplThree": three,
            "tplTwo": two
        };

    var html = Mustache.to_html(one, json, partials);
    $('#mustacheContainer').html(html);
}, "html");
```

This outputs the expected "joe blogs" as​ demonstrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/tbs6N/)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar and wrote a quick function to take an arbitrary template file and generate an appropriate partials variable:

```
  var partials = {};
  $.ajax({
    'url': '/templates/common.mustache',
    'async': false,
    'success': function( template_partials ) {
      $(template_partials).filter( 'script' ).each(function(index,piece) {
        partials[piece.id] = piece.innerHTML;
      })
    }});

  var html = $.mustache(template, jsonData, partials)
  $("div.content").html(html);
```

This may also help to clean up and generalize your code a little.